# Nested Resource - Controller to filter by current_user also

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thanks to some help in another question, I now have a nested resource setup, and it is nearly working the way I need it to.  This is a follow-up question about the controller.

Expenses have both a user, and a project that they belong to.

I would like to visit /projects/5/expenses, and see a list of all the expenses for that project, (which IS working), but also have it sensitive to the user that is currently signed in, so they only see their own expenses.

first the models:

```
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :project_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

end
```

each of the other models has "has_many :expenses", to complete the relationship.

so my route looks like:

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :expenses
  end
```

And

```
class ExpensesController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @user = current_user  
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @expense_list = @project.expenses.all  
end
```

How can I filter my @expense_list further by only showing the current_user's expenses?

Comment: Might not be the best solution (so rather a comment): You could use `@project.expenses.find_all_by_user_id(@user.id)` to get all expenses which are bound to the project and the current user

Comment: That definitely works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a an additional condition to query the expenses based on the user that they belong to. 
I would suggest that you create a scope in your Expense model

```
scope :for_user, lambda{ |user| 
      where( :user_id => user.id )
   }
```

And you can do this in the controller:

```
@expense_list = @project.expenses.for_user(current_user).all
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the insight.